# How to display Woocommerce products sorted by product tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I'm building a woocommerce website using storefront.
On each category page, I wish to display product ordered by tag.
Each product has only one tag.

TAG 1
product a
product b
TAG 2
product x
product y

I think I can retrieve all the data I need from the DB.
But I have no clue how to use them to display my products ordered by tags.

**EDITED**

```
// GET CATEGORY ID
$currentCategory = get_queried_object();
$catSlug = $currentCategory->slug;
// GET PRODCUTS FROM CURRENT CATEGORY
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'product_cat' => $catSlug,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);
$prodLoop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $prodLoop->have_posts() ){
    $prodLoop->the_post();
    global $product;
    echo the_title();
    echo the_ID();
    echo '</br>';
}
// GET TAGS ID
$tag_args = array(
    'taxonomy'               => 'product_tag',
    'orderby'                => 'name',
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'             => false,
);
$tag_query = new WP_Term_Query($tag_args);
foreach($tag_query->get_terms() as $term){
    print_r($term->term_id);
}

//GET ALL PRODUCTS ID
$prod_args = new WC_Product_Query( array(
    'limit' => 5,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'return' => 'ids',
));
$products = $prod_args->get_products();
foreach($products as $prod){
    print_r($prod);
}
```

I read many things, maybe I could you a SELECT xxx query, something like a one to many realtionship query, or an usort function, but I don't know where to do... I tried many things, but by now all I got is a headache and feeling hopeless...

Comment: Is not possible to order by products based on a taxonomy in the query loop, so in your case the taxonomy is "product_tag" for Product tags, as a product can have many terms set in it. So this is complicated and you will need to build a custom template with multiple nested queries (nested loops) for your product category archive pages. So your question is simply too broad actually for StackOverFlow.

Comment: Oh.. ok. Thank you for not letting me search and waste time forever... I thought a comparison on IDs would have done the job, as my products only have one tag. If you are aware of a plugin I could use, it would be very welcome. Thanks again.

Comment: See this related thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy … So I don't thing that you will find a plugin for that, this requires custom development.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec, I finally chose tu use subcategories and the Nested Category Layout plugin. I didn't want to go that way because many of the nested categories will have the same name and it will be a content bload, but nevermind... Thank you for your help

Comment: I think that it's a much better and accurate way.